# How to compile `Hello, World!` Linux kernel module in Eclipse CDT?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, eclipse-cdt, kernel-module

I want to develop Linux kernel module by Eclipse IDE, any one could help how configure Eclipse CDT to compile and run [this kernel module](http://blog.markloiseau.com/2012/04/hello-world-loadable-kernel-module-tutorial/) ?

Answer (score 1):

@Khajavi, Please follow the steps below,

1) Go to File --> New --> Project --> A dialog box pops up, then

2) Under C/C++ --> Select "Makefile Project with Existing Code" and select "Next"

3) Fill Project Name, Language and Toolchain used, browse and select the location where
   your kernel source --- select "OK" and select "Finish"

4) Project will be created and shown on the left hand side of Eclipse IDE. Right click on 
   the project folder and select "Properties"

5) Select C/C++ Build option, find tabs such as "Builder Settings" "Behavior" on the RHS 
   dialog. Let the Builder settings be as it is, but in the Behavior tab delete "all"
   part of "Build (Incremental Build)", apply and exit.

[image]

If you want your kernel module to be cross compiled, then configure the "Builder Settings" as below

[image]

Thus eclipse settings are configured and can compile or clean your module :-)